# Moduli of semistable sheaves as fiber bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over a field of char 0, and $F$ a stable $\mathscr{O}_X$-module of rank $r$ and determinant bundle $Q$. There is a natural morphism $\operatorname{det}:M\to \operatorname{Pic}(X)$ from the moduli space of semistable sheaves of $X$ (with respect to a fixed ample bundle and Hilbert polynomial) to the Picard scheme. I want to prove that $\operatorname{det}$ realizes $M$ as a fiber bundle over an etale neighborhood of $[Q]$. The following argument is from  ``Geometry of Moduli Spaces of Sheaves, page 114'':

> Let $M(Q)$ be the fiber of the $\operatorname{det}$ over the point $[Q]$.  Tensorizing a sheaf $E$ of rank $r$ by a line bundle $B$ twists the determinant bundle $\operatorname{det}(E)$ by $B^r$. Moreover, if $B$ is numerically trivial, $E\otimes B$ is semistable or stable if and only if $E$ is semistable, respectively. If follows from this that $\operatorname{det}:M\to\operatorname{Pic}(X)$ is surjective in a neighborhood of $[Q]$ and is, in fact, a fiber bundle with fiber $M(Q)$ in an etale neighborhood of $[Q]$.

For simplicity we may assume that $Q=\mathscr{O}_X$. Then does it means that there is a neighborhood of the origin of $\operatorname{Pic}$ where all bundles are numerically trivial and we can take $r$-th root of them? Even so, if  all fibers near $[Q]$ of $\operatorname{det}$ are isomorphic, how it implies that $M$ is a fiber bundle? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  Form the base change of the morphism $\text{det}$ by the covering space map from $\text{Pic}$ to itself by multiplication by $n$.  Then the description by Huybrechts and Lehn describe the base change as a product manifold with its projection to $\text{Pic}$.  Since the base changed by the covering space map is a (product) fiber bundle, the original $\text{det}$ morphism is a fiber bundle.

Comment: @JasonStarr Great! But i still have a question. Why the multiplication by $n$ is an etale covering?

Comment: I recommend that you look at a textbook on group varieties and Picard groups, maybe Mumford's book, "Abelian varieties."  Every group scheme over a characteristic $0$ field is smooth using Cartier's work.  So the multiplication by $n$ map is a morphism of smooth group schemes.  The kernel is finite, and it is a subgroup scheme, hence it is finite and reduced.  It follows that the multiplication by $n$ morphism is etale.  Smoothness of $X$ implies the connected components of the Picard scheme are proper.  So the multiplication by $n$ map is also proper, hence it is a finite morphism.